# XPages and EL concat

Tags: xpages, el, concatenation

I am trying to implement the example at http://lpar.ath0.com/2014/04/07/repeated-xpages-input-controls-with-number-indexed-field-names/

I've got it working. This is the call to the composite control:

```
<xc:track_row row="#{rownum}" fieldName="Track#{rownum}" dataSource="#{document1}" />
```

However, what I'd like is to save fields with the 01, 02 concatenated instead of  1, 2 etc. I've tried

```
fieldName="Track#{(rownum lt 10)? '0'.concat(rownum):rownum}"
```

However that generates an EL syntax error on that line. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Sorry I rushed to answer your question and got confused with something else that doesn't work, as Sven rightly pointed out, you can use EL for IF, but what you are unable to do is pass method params to a function via EL in JSF1.1 and therefore XPages. So calling bean.myMethod(param) via EL would fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use multiple EL statements, it is a String only. All EL notations will be replaced during processing of the expressions. You can solve it this way:

```
fieldName="Track#{(rownum lt 10)? '0':''}#{rownum}"
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks so much Sven.